# Load up javascript files after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Hi how do i go about loading up my javascript files after an ajax call has been made, reason being it seems once i click submit, some javascript functions do not end up working. I tried using "$getscript" however it was a bit buggy especially in google chrome? This is what my call looks like;

```
function InsertStatus() {
    var fStatus1 = document.getElementById('<%=txtStatus.ClientID %>').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebServices/UserList.asmx/InsertUserStatus",
        data: "{ 'fStatus': '" + fStatus1 + "' }",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d == "Successful") {
                $("#col-3").load(location.href + " #col-3>*", "");
                $.getScript('scripts/script.js', function () {
                });
            }
            else {
                alert("its false");
                $.getScript('scripts/script.js', function () {
                });
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$.getScript('scripts/script.js', function () {});`

With:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'script',
    url: 'scripts/script.js',
    crossDomain:true,
    success: function(response)
    {
        //Whatever
    }
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for responding, i tried using this and it is still buggy sometimes it downloads the file, other times it doesnt.